# Getting response body on failed request with HttpRequestException

Tags: c#, .net, httpclient

I am trying to log failed requests from my `HttpRequestException`.

My server returns error code **and** additional JSON payload at the response body. I need to access that JSON. How do I read the response body in case of an errored request? I know that the actual response is not null. It's an API and I confirm that it returns JSON payload with 4xx status codes, giving detailed insight about the error.

How do I access it? Here is my code:

```
using (var httpClient = new HttpClient())
{
    try
    {
        string resultString = await httpClient.GetStringAsync(endpoint);
        var result = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<...>(resultString);
        return result;
    }
    catch (HttpRequestException ex)
    {
        throw ex;
    }
}
```

I am trying to get data in `throw ex` line, but I couldn't find a way.

Comment: I don't know if this might help you at all. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10928528/receiving-json-data-back-from-http-request

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Exactly as @Frédéric suggested, if you use `GetAsync` method you'll get the proper `HttpResponseMessage` object which give more information about the response. To get details when error occurs you can deserialize the errors to an `Exception` or your custom exception object from Response content like below:

```
public static Exception CreateExceptionFromResponseErrors(HttpResponseMessage response)
{
    var httpErrorObject = response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;

    // Create an anonymous object to use as the template for deserialization:
    var anonymousErrorObject =
        new { message = "", ModelState = new Dictionary<string, string[]>() };

    // Deserialize:
    var deserializedErrorObject =
        JsonConvert.DeserializeAnonymousType(httpErrorObject, anonymousErrorObject);

    // Now wrap into an exception which best fullfills the needs of your application:
    var ex = new Exception();

    // Sometimes, there may be Model Errors:
    if (deserializedErrorObject.ModelState != null)
    {
        var errors =
            deserializedErrorObject.ModelState
                                    .Select(kvp => string.Join(". ", kvp.Value));
        for (int i = 0; i < errors.Count(); i++)
        {
            // Wrap the errors up into the base Exception.Data Dictionary:
            ex.Data.Add(i, errors.ElementAt(i));
        }
    }
    // Othertimes, there may not be Model Errors:
    else
    {
        var error =
            JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Dictionary<string, string>>(httpErrorObject);
        foreach (var kvp in error)
        {
            // Wrap the errors up into the base Exception.Data Dictionary:
            ex.Data.Add(kvp.Key, kvp.Value);
        }
    }
    return ex;
}
```

**Usage:**

```
        using (var client = new HttpClient())
        {
            var response =
                await client.GetAsync("http://localhost:51137/api/Account/Register");


            if (!response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
            {
                // Unwrap the response and throw as an Api Exception:
                var ex = CreateExceptionFromResponseErrors(response);
                throw ex;
            }
        }
```

Here's the [source](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/825274/ASP-NET-Web-Api-Unwrapping-HTTP-Error-Results-and) article detailing more about handling the HttpResponseMessage and it's content.

Answer (score 4):

Use [`GetAsync`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.http.httpclient.getasync) instead of `GetStringAsync`. `GetAsync` will not throw an exception and will allow you to access response content, status code and any other header you may require.

See this [page](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-api/overview/advanced/calling-a-web-api-from-a-net-client#GettingResource) for more.

Answer (score 2):

Essentially what @RyanGunn posted but implemented in your code.

You should be able to `ReadAsStringAsync` from the `resultString.Content`

I am working on an SDK that employs similar code except we use a switch statement to check for various `HttpStatusCodes` that we intend to return before the `DeserializeObject` line.

```
using (var httpClient = new HttpClient())
{
    try
    {
        string resultString = await httpClient.GetStringAsync(endpoint);
        var result = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<...>(resultString.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result);
        return result;
    }
    catch (HttpRequestException ex)
    {
        throw ex;
    }
}
```