# REST API cannot be accessed by the C# Windows Form

Tags: java, c#, rest, intellij-idea, spring-boot

I have develop a REST API using Spring Boot and IntelliJ IDEA. That API is up and running. It is accessible by Postman & it gives the relevant JSON response.

Then I tried to access it from C# windows form application. I tried to add it as a web reference. But that button has been disabled.
What is the problem with my code?

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/students")
public class StudentController {

@Autowired
private StudentService studentService;

@RequestMapping(value="/hello")
String home() {
    return "Hello World!";
}

@RequestMapping(value="getAllStudents",method = RequestMethod.GET)
public Collection<Student> getAllStudents(){
    return studentService.getAllStudents();
}

@RequestMapping(value = "/{id}",method = RequestMethod.GET)
public Student getStudentById(@PathVariable("id") int id)
{
    return studentService.getStudentById(id);
}


@RequestMapping(value = "/{id}" , method = RequestMethod.DELETE)
public void deleteStudentById(@PathVariable("id") int id)
{
studentService.removeStudentById(id);
}
```

If I gives the URL as *localhost:8080/students/hello* the JSON response come to the visual studio. But it cannot be added as web reference.

[image]

What is the solution for this...?

Comment: Main problem of your C# code is that its Java code

Comment: I never consumed REST API in .NET, but I always believed that `Web reference` in visual studio is intended to be use with SOAP web service. To consume a REST API, I think you need to build it on your own with `HttpClient` or use a 3rd party library.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Web References in Visual Studio are meant for SOAP/ASMX web services. If you are calling a REST API then, as @fharreau commented you'lld need to use HttpClient.

The link shows you how to do it, but it may be difficult to read/follow:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-api/overview/advanced/calling-a-web-api-from-a-net-client

This SO answer might be better

https://stackoverflow.com/a/10928807/2309376

In the SO answer you will need to replace the "http://www.contoso.com/" with your URL "http://localhost:8080/students/hello"

Comment: Thank you @Simply Ged. &  fharreau  But I used .NET just to consume my web service from a web client application. I tried to add that web service to java web client in netbeans. Same problem there.
Netbeans says "Cannot determine if the service is of type WSDL or WADL"

Comment: @Chamith : Are you using WinForms or a web client? Unclear what you ask. Anyway, WSDL is the interface contract for SOAP Web Services. I never heard about WADL (just look about it and IMHO, it is an aberration but that's not the point) and I am not a Java specialist but I assume nothing in your Java code generate such a file. I guess this is why you cannot open it in NetBeans.