# Post request .Net 5.0

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-core, .net-5

I’m trying to write a Post request in the custom function. In php can be written using CURL, What about dotnet? What’s the best way to convert the below code to .Net?

```
$header = array(
      'Authorization: Basic '. base64_encode(Key).’:’)
    );

    $curl = curl_init(‘URL’);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $header);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 60);
    $response = json_decode(curl_exec($curl), true);
```

I didn't have any experience in .net. I hope find the answer

Find a solution of send request use .net 5.0

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Receiving JSON data back from HTTP request](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10928528/receiving-json-data-back-from-http-request)

Comment: Side note: .NET 5 is now out of support, you should upgrade.

Comment: You'd use `HttpClient`.

Comment: What are you posting? The code you posted sets some headers but no body.

Answer (score -1):

.Net 5 is for web application and we have [official document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/http-requests?view=aspnetcore-5.0) here.

Firstly, we need to inject http service into our project, which is the first step in the document doing. Adding `services.AddHttpClient();` in the `Startup.cs/ConfigureServices` method which is used to inject `IHttpClientFactory`, so that we could use this http module in our main method.

Then in your method, you need to inject `IHttpClientFactory` into the constructor method.

```
public class YourClass
{
    private readonly IHttpClientFactory _clientFactory;


    public YourClass(IHttpClientFactory clientFactory)
    {
        _clientFactory = clientFactory;
    }
    
    public async Task YourMethod()
    {
        var request = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Get, "url");
        request.Headers.Add("Authorization", "Basic "+"your_custom_key");

        var client = _clientFactory.CreateClient();

        var response = await client.SendAsync(request);

        if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
        {
            using var responseStream = await response.Content.ReadAsStreamAsync();
            var res = await JsonSerializer.DeserializeAsync<IEnumerable<JsonResponse>>(responseStream);//if the json response is a list
            //var res = await JsonSerializer.DeserializeAsync<JsonResponse>(responseStream);//if the json response is a object
        }
    }
}

public class JsonResponse{
    public string propertyOne{get; set;}
    public int propertyTwo{get; set;}
}
```